# What are chromosome dimers and how do they relate to recombination?

Tags: genetics, microbiology

I am reading the book *Molecular Genetics of Bacteria 4th ed.* and I don't fully understand the concept/visual representation of dimer chromosomes. Consider the following quote (pg 35):

> an odd number of crossovers occurring between any 2 sequences on the 2 daughter DNAs in the dimer will resolve the dimer, but an even number of crossovers will recreate a dimer.

[image]

In panel 2, did another recombination event occur to yield 2 daughter chromosomes with the same sequences? The colors made me think they each might not have had their original complete sequence.

Thank you for the answer to my crossover occurrence question and their relation to dimer formation and resolution.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I wanted to improve the format of your post but I was not exactly sure what you were asking. I've made an edit feel free to roll back if you don't like it. Also, if you accept the edit, you should definitely edit the `<insert something>` elements. +1 btw

Comment: The quote is not so specific to bacterial genetics as much as to genetic recombination in general. Have a look [**at this answer**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35803/genetic-linkage-greater-than-50-centimorgans/53876#53876) to understand why the question of whether an even or an odd number of recombination events occur between two loci matter.

Comment: Your question is rather broad. It would be better to ask about something specific that is confusing you about chromosome dimers.

Comment: Is your question why an even number of crossovers will recreate the dimer during resolution? That can be answered, though it would help if you explained why this doesn't make sense to you.