# Cis and trans linkage

Tags: recombination, genetic-linkage

**Question**:

> Two dominant non-allelic genes are 50map units apart, the linkage is:
>
> (A) Cis type
>
> (B) Trans Type
>
> (C) Complete
>
> (D) Absent/Incomplete

**My take:**

After a lot of searching on the net I found that 50 map units =50% recombination frequency. And no recombination happens  when it is 50 map units or more than that.
But there is no information given about cis and trans linkage with that of map units.
Even though the answer for the above question is absent or incomplete (d),the options bugged me to ask this question

*Is it possible to guess cis /trans linkage when map units are given?* If i am wrong please correct me. Thanks in advance !

Comment: 50cM ≠ 0.5 probability of recombination. See [Difference between crossover rate and recombination rate?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35803/genetic-linkage-greater-than-50-centimorgans)

Comment: Yep...i understood that ! Only genes  less than 50cM apart  can be recombined right?

Comment: It would be better if you post the question from your textbook (or exercise) as a text instead of an image.

Comment: As far as I know, cis and trans require the knowledge of which alleles of two traits are present and how they are linked. But based on the "two dominant" thing in the question, if there were linkage, it would have been cis type linkage. [A random page on the first page of Google search, if it helps.](http://passel.unl.edu/pages/informationmodule.php?idinformationmodule=980265683&topicorder=10&maxto=14)